# Is there a simple way to group multiple lines of a command output based on a beginning and end match?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep, zsh

Is there a simple way to group multiple lines which match a pattern into single lines?

Basically, the output of a command lists something like:

```
key1 blah blah = dict {

   unrelated stuff {

   }

   something I actually want to match via grep or something

   some common end term for key1 I can use as an end pattern match
}

x 100 similar keys
```

My end-game here in this specific case is to strip an XML of entries which have a specific entry within them. I could do this (and solve a lot of other day-to-day problems) if each entry was its own line instead of multi-line (`grep` in the matches, `sed` out the text after the bracket, etc.)

Something like:

```
print multi-line crap | merge beginningpattern endpattern | grep lines now that everything is merged
```

Basically the 'merged' command would strip all linefeeds between every new `beginningpattern` and `endpattern` (maybe putting a linefeed at the end)

Comment: is your input a JSON or a python dict ?

Answer (score 0):

awk and gsub would be the right way, if I understand your question correctly. For example:

```
required_string=$(cat $i.xml | awk 'BEGIN { x=0 ; y=0} /<yourStartingString>/ { x=1 } /<EndingString>/ {x=0} {if (x==1 && y==1) { gsub(/(.*<grepforwhatyouneed>)|(<endgrep>)/,"");print } } { if(x==1 && y==0) y=1 }')
```